# How to create a dataframe from a RDD in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a RDD looks like this

```
[((0, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B109F|', day=u'Fri')), 0), 
 ((1, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B1115|HIGH MOUNTED STOP LAMP CONTROL', day=u'Sat')), 2)]
```

which has an index, a Row object (`event_type_new` and `day`), followed by a prediction (integer). How can I create a DataFrame with 3 columns including `event_type_new`, `day`, and `Prediction`.

I am using Spark 1.6.2 with PySpark API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your list into RDD first. Then map each element to `Row`. You can transform list of `Row` to dataframe easily using `.toDF()` method

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

ls = [((0, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B109F|', day=u'Fri')), 0),
      ((1, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B1115|HIGH MOUNTED STOP LAMP CONTROL', day=u'Sat')), 2)]
ls_rdd = sc.parallelize(ls)
ls_row = ls_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**{'day': str(x[0][1].day), 'event_type': str(x[0][1].event_type_new), 'prediction': int(x[1])}))
df = ls_row.toDF()
```

When you run `df.show()`, it will look like this:

```
+---+--------------------+----------+
|day|          event_type|prediction|
+---+--------------------+----------+
|Fri|ALERT|VEHICLE_HEA...|         0|
|Sat|ALERT|VEHICLE_HEA...|         2|
+---+--------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Had to explicitly define types in the map to make it work. Like this ls_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**{'day': str(x[0][1].day), 'event_type': str(x[0][1].event_type_new), 'prediction': int(x[1])}))

Comment: Thanks @Isaac! I'll update the solution according to the comment. My Spark version is 2.1 and I guess it implicitly infers the data type.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this a `collected RDD`, because it looks like you got a `list` with tuples of a combination of `Row` and `int` objects. You can get your desired output with the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row


lst = [((0, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B109F|', day=u'Fri')), 0),
       ((1, Row(event_type_new=u'ALERT|VEHICLE_HEALTH_DATA|CHANGE_IN_HEALTH|DTC|B1115|HIGH MOUNTED STOP LAMP CONTROL', day=u'Sat')), 2)]

output = []
for row in lst:
    vals = tuple(row[0][1]) + (row[1],)
    fields = row[0][1].__fields__ + ['prediction']
    row = Row(*vals)
    row.__fields__ = fields
    output.append(row)

df = sc.parallelize(output).toDF()
df.show()
```

You should get something like the following:

```
+---+--------------------+----------+
|day|      event_type_new|prediction|
+---+--------------------+----------+
|Fri|ALERT|VEHICLE_HEA...|         0|
|Sat|ALERT|VEHICLE_HEA...|         2|
+---+--------------------+----------+
```

I hope this helps.